# amcharts, disable panning only when zoomed out

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4, ammap

How can I disable panning (dragging) in AmCharts map only when it's fully zoomed out.

I tried using `chart.seriesContainer.draggable = false;` but it completely disable the panning, but i wanna be able to drag the map when I zoom in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [adjust map interaction behavior](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Interacting_with_map) via the [`MapChart.panBehavior` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapchart/#panBehavior_property) and monitor for when the `zoomLevel` has changed via the `"zoomlevelchanged"` event, e.g.:

```js
chart.panBehavior = "none";
chart.events.on("zoomlevelchanged", function(){
  // queue event loop so a final zoomlevelchanged can be "cauight"
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      if (chart.zoomLevel <= 1) {
        chart.panBehavior = "none";
      } else if (chart.zoomLevel > 1) {
        chart.panBehavior = "move";
      }
    }, 0);
});
```

Here's a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/8d767bd62c8cb238ecb633e2123317ed